# Workaround for CSS reset overwriting deprecated HTML attributes (e.g. align, bgcolor)?

Tags: html, css, html-table, deprecated

I have a website that gets updated through a WYSIWYG editor by people with very little HTML knowledge. The WYSIWYG exports table-based structure with old deprecated tags like "align" and "bgcolor" onto a site that is CSS driven so these attributes get overwritten.

For example, a black background is applied to a table in the WYSIWYG editor but once it goes live on the site, the background defaults back to none (default) because of the site's CSS reset.

Is there a way to account for these old tags the CSS is overwriting that I might not be seeing without getting rid of the reset CSS, creating additional CSS markup or upgrading the WYSIWYG tool?

Comment: Users shouldn't have access to creative tools! ^_^

Answer (score 3):

Ideally, you shouldn't be using a WYSIWYG editor which generates table-based layouts and deprecated attributes — it's just bad semantics.

I'd suggest upgrading to a better editor, such as TinyMCE, since there's no way you can make attribute styling override your CSS rules.

Answer (score 1):

You could use JavaScript to replace the bum-attributes with RegEx?

replace() - http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp

RegEx - http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html

Answer (score 0):

No. CSS explicitly overrides any presentational markup in the document.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to do **some** work to get it going,

The best option IMO is to style the classes for these elements in CSS and allow them to be overridden.